# Impossible to show this analytically (without numerical methods)?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, optimization

Let $f(x):=-xe^{-x^2}$ then we have that $\inf_{x \in \mathbb{R}} f(x)=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2e}} \approx -0.429$

[see wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%20infimum%28-x*e%5E%28-x%5E2%29%29%20)

Now define $g(x):=f(x)-0.01 f'''(x)$ then we have that $\inf_{x \in \mathbb{R}}g(x) \approx - 0.408$

[see wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=infimum%28-x*e%5E%28-x%5E2%29-0.01*%286%20-%2024%20x%5E2%20%2B%208%20x%5E4%29%2FE%5Ex%5E2%29)

Now I want to show analytically that $\inf_{x \in \mathbb{R}} f(x)< \inf_{x \in \mathbb{R}} g(x).$ But I have the feeling that this is impossible as the method of calculating extrema via $g'(x)=0$ leads to a fifth-order polynomial equation.

So is it really not possible to show this fact analytically or is there a work-around? In particular, I am not interested in the precise values, I only want to show that the infimum of $f$ is strictly smaller than the one of $g$.

You maybe also want to have a look at the graph where the one with the lower peak (red) is of course $f$ and the other one $g$.[image]
If anything is unclear, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x) = g(x)$ when $4 x^4 - 12 x^2 + 3 = 0$, which we solve as a quadratic in $x^2$ to get $ = \pm \dfrac{\sqrt{6 \pm 2 \sqrt{6}}}{2}$.  Call these 
points (in order left to right) $a_1$, $a_2$, $a_3$, $a_4$.  You can then show that:

1. For $x \le 0$,  since $x^4 e^{-x^2} < 4 e^{-2} < 1$ and $e^{-x^2} \le 1$ we have $$g(x) =  \left(-\dfrac{3}{50} - x + \dfrac{6}{25} x^2 - \dfrac{2}{25} x^4\right) e^{-x^2} \ge \left(-\dfrac{3}{50} - \dfrac{2}{25} x^4\right) e^{-x^2} \ge -\dfrac{3}{50}-\dfrac{2}{25} = -0.14$$
2. On $a_2 \le x \le a_3$, both $f$ and $g$ are decreasing, so $g(x) \ge g(a_3) = f(a_3)$.
3. On $a_3 \le x \le a_4$, $g(x) \ge f(x) $.
4. On $a_4 \le x$, both $f$ and $g$ are increasing, so $g(x) \ge g(a_4) = f(a_4)$.

In all four cases, therefore, we have $g(x) \ge \inf_{t\in \mathbb R} f(t)$.

Comment: well, even 1. semms to be wrong. $g(x)$ seems to be in fact negative for small enough $-x$ (take x=-10$)

Comment: Oops, slight glitch there... I'll edit.